# What version of Oracle SQL Developer do I need to use to connect to Oracle 8i?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle8i

Our production application uses Oracle 8i with an embedded license. We do not have control over it so updating our Oracle version is not possible.

What version of Oracle SQL Developer would I need to use to connect to our Oracle 8i database?

The latest versions obviously do not work as Oracle 8i is not supported. What version would I need to use so that it allows me to connect?

Comment: I think it depends on the `JDBC` driver version.

Answer (score 0):

A similar thread on OraFAQ  has the following suggestion which seems promising as I too think it depends on the `JDBC` driver version. The suggestion is :

> SQL Developer version 1.2.1 is able to connect to 8.1.7 with limited
>   functionality (prepared reports and browser for objects could not
>   work)..
>
> Next version (tested with 3.2 64-bit) of SQL developer could be
>   "hacked" to connect to 8.1.7 by simply copy file
>   C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\classes12.zip from Oracle
>   client prior 11 into appropriate jdk\jre\lib\ext folder.

[source](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/177095/)

Answer (score 0):

I use SqlDeveloper 1.5.5 for my **Oracle Database 8**.

But if the Table list is empty use **SqlDeveloper 1.2.1**